# Left Ctrl key opening help and right Ctrl key prints "x"

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I don't know how, but somehow the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys on my keyboard have messed up. Left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is opening a help window and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key prints the "x" character. I tried setting/re-setting keyboard shortcuts and rebooting the system but that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like your keyboard has been re - mapped, try mapping it to the defaults, I know this can be done on windows but not sure about Ubuntu

Comment: i tried to restore it to defaults but not working. Nothing has been mapped in keyboard shortcuts as well.

Comment: I haven't used Ubuntu much but this might help - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultimediaKeys

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try going to **System Settings** (in Unity, from the indicator menu on the top-right), then click **Keyboard** from Hardware section, and click button **Restore default**.

If it does not work, check the selected keyboard model, and check also the there is no strange flags in list appearing clicking on **Options** button.